# How to start java project's exe file as windows service?

Tags: java, windows, service

hi i tried to start java project's exe file as a service from command sc create "ServiceName" binpath= "fullpath\Service.exe" start= auto it has been added to services but when i restart my PC it's status is stopped when i mannualy start it from services window it says  Error 1053 : The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion  i ve tried HKEY too but nothing happened  any idea?

Comment: [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You need a wrapper to really make a java program as a Windows service.

Take a look at  [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) .