# Executable jar file not running as windows service

Tags: windows-services

I created an executable jar file from jsmooth. I created an exe from inno setup and added the below code in run block to add my executable jar to windows service

Filename: "{sys}\sc.exe"; Parameters: "create service-name start= auto binPath= ""{app}\application-name.exe""";

It is adding to windows service but I am getting 1053 error when I try to start my service

Comment: A service isn't just an ordinary application that you install with `sc`.  The service executable has to interface with the service control manager.  I'm not sure whether you can do that directly in Java, but you could investigate [Apache Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/), Microsoft's [srvany](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/137890), or [nssm](https://nssm.cc/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start java project's exe file as windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221230/how-to-start-java-projects-exe-file-as-windows-service)